# Navbar has no style using Bootstrap 4

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

My Navbar doesn't apply any style, not even the defaults:
[Navbar collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXGLy.png)

[Navbar expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NI8yg.png)

In head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

And in body:

```
<body <?php body_class($twichies_classes); ?>

<div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xl-12">

                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-fixed-top navbar-dark danger-color">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                            </button>
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                                My Theme
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                            <?php 
                                wp_nav_menu(array(
                                    'theme_location' => 'primary',
                                    'container' => false,
                                    'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'
                                    )
                                );
                            ?>
                            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
                </nav>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

At the very end:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Already tried different class settings e.g. changed to default but it only changes the colour of "My Theme". It seems like that the wp_nav_menu items make it look weird.. any ideas? Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: make sure that your **php code** after **<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">** inside the list like as shown.  **<ul><li><a href='#'>your menu</a></li></ul>** This will solve your problem.

Comment: I'm using the theme support by wordpress so it's their list which shouldn't be the issue I guess? Even if I use the given (list) code by bootstrap I don't get the default Navbar style..

Comment: I didn't know about the wordpress. But in html it should work. And I think trying and checking once is good. By doing so you will be confirmed about it.

Comment: I just created a new html file with the given code by bootstrap (4) without any php code and also checked the css link and scripts once again and it still has no style! I don't get it..

Comment: See below. I have written the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Image 1]

When the screen is small on click on menu it will show the following image.

[image: Imge 2]

This is the image of navbar.

In your code I have changed

**This**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-fixed-top navbar-dark danger-color">
```

**To**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark danger-color" style="background: #000;">
```

And the php code after this line

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
```

**To**

```
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Here I haven't use any css here.